# Error when attempting to remove node from parent using fast enumeration

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

After Upgrading to iOS 8 b3 and Xcode 6 b3 I get an error in the didSimulatePhysics method:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"name" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.y < 0 || node.position.x>320 || node.position.x<0) {
        [node removeFromParent];
    }
}];
```

Although I have exception breakpoint enabled and zombie objects I have no further info of why this is happening. The error is Thread 1 BreakPoint 1.3. [level didSimulatePhysics]
Any help is much appreciated.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x7edf17d0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

Comment: That's not enough information; if you cannot provide more then there is nothing anyone here can do (IMHO).

Comment: @trojanfoe how can I get more info about the error?

Comment: @trojanfoe edited with more info

Comment: OK look for code that iterates an `NSMutableArray` and attempts to change it within the loop.  This is the cause of the exception.

Comment: @trojanfoe believe it or not I do NOT have a single array in my scene. I tried running this project in Xcode 5 and I get no errors whatsoever. Do you think is an Xcode b3 bug?

Comment: I'm not sure; it's possible of course, but more likely a bug in iOS, not Xcode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Behavior may change between iOS versions. It may have actually crashed at some point or very rarely even in Xcode 5, you just didn't get to see it.

The problem is easily circumvented by delaying the execution of the removeFromParent method. This should do the trick because actions are evaluated at a specific point in the game loop rather than instantaneously:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"name" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.y < 0 || node.position.x>320 || node.position.x<0) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent]];
    }
}];
```

If this won't work use the "old trick": filling an NSMutableArray with to-be-deleted items and removing the nodes in that array after enumeration:

```
NSMutableArray* toBeDeleted = [NSMutableArray array];

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"name" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.y < 0 || node.position.x>320 || node.position.x<0) {
        [toBeDeleted addObject:node];
    }
}];

for (CCNode* node in toBeDeleted)
{
    [node removeFromParent];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but unfortunately it did not work this way. So the work around is to fill an NSMutableArray with the node after [self addChild..] and remove it in a loop in [self enumerate..]? Wont this cause more performance issues (running a loop in enumerate-block)?

Comment: edited answer with code example for delete array ... it shouldn't be a performance issue, or would you rather the app crashes or run slightly less efficient? ;)

Comment: No change whatsoever. Same error. I think its a bug in b3 because I got no error in b2 nor b1. Can someone else check this?

Comment: With the second code sample, where exactly does the crash occur? Try it with exception breakpoint added.

Comment: Are you perhaps running a background thread that adds or removes child nodes?

Comment: I am but thats only to remove child nodes. When "falling" or "projecting" nodes exit the screen I have to remove them at some point. (when dealing with more than 200 nodes each "game run"). Also when running NSLog(@"Chilren: %lu", (unsigned long)self.children.count); in method this gets called once the scene is presented and runs continuesly even if the nodes containing the physics body are removed from the parent. is there a way to stop this?

Comment: After reporting it as a bug apple engineers reported back to me stating that:
"Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based on the following: You can't remove nodes inside didSimulatePhysics."