# Remove nodes after moving off screen

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, sprite-kit

Here is a newbie question. I am trying to remove nodes "rocks" after the fall off screen. This is what I applied in GameScene.m to which the nodes are added.

```
    -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"rock" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.y < 0) {
        [node removeFromParent];
    }
}];
```

}

This looks fine, however I get error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x608000046360> was mutated while being enumerated.'

I know what it means but how else can I remove nodes?

Context: I am following [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW14) from Apple.

Comment: duplicate, because it's basically the same concept as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457369/collection-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated-error-in-objective-c

Comment: @prototypical not really, because this question is not about the error but different SKNode removal possibilities. (But I'm sure somewhere there will a question about that, too)

Comment: @robert It's the same issue/concept, different collection type. Does this look familiar--> "was mutated while being enumerated." Same error as in the post I linked to.

Comment: I do see the point that it's about node removal within this concept, however I'd hope what gets learned is the concept causing the error itself. But definitely your answer provides an option to solve it in this specific case, so I guess you are right. upvoted your answer.

Comment: This is the question I was thinking of, I knew this sounded familiar but I didn't find it in my search initially - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626462/thread-1-breakpoint-1-3-using-spritekit

Comment: It is a duplicate, however this one is worded better in my opinion and less convoluted. The title of that question is not at all ideal :)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and the effort to find a real duplicate. :) I'm totally with you that the concept causing the error should be learned. Just didn't include it in my answer because he said he would know what the error means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a remove action on the nodes:

```
[node runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent]];
```