# swift - multithreading error by using enumerateChildNodesWithName

Tags: multithreading, swift, sprite-kit

I like to use multithreading in my spritekit game.
I use enumerateChildNodesWithName and then I check if this object has collided with the player. I want to execute this part on another thread.

Here is my code: `let updateQueue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("my.game", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)`

```
dispatch_async(updateQueue, { () -> Void in
            self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("lockGreen", usingBlock: { (lockGreen, stop) -> Void in
                if CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, lockGreen.frame) && keyGreenCollected {
                    lockGreen.removeFromParent()
                }
            })
        })
```

But I get this error. How can I fix this?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',   reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x1702407b0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1827c822c 0x1944940e4 0x1827c7be0 0x1870ca4bc 0x1870c9c08 0x1870c95a0 0x1000ea904 0x1000e722c 0x100954fd4 0x100954f94 0x10095e8f0 0x100954f94 0x100962b54 0x100964248 0x194cf121c 0x194cf0ee0)`
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are modifying a collection while looping over its elements. It has nothing to do with multi-threading.

Removing a node from its parent, with `removeFromParent`, removes the node from the parent's node tree. It also removes the node from its parent's `children` array. The error occurs because you are modifying the `self.children` array (with `removeFromParent`) while looping over elements of the array with `enumerateChildNodesWithName`.

Comment: I suggest you avoid using `enumerateChildNodesWithName` because it can be extremely slow. Alternatively, you can create an `SKNode` called `lockGreens` and add the `lockGreen` nodes to the `lockGreens` `SKNode`. You can then iterate over the nodes with `for i in stride(from: lockGreens.children.count-1, through: 0, by: -1) {...}`. Because the loop iterates backwards, you can safely remove the nodes from the node tree and `children` array.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your problem has anything to do with multithreading.

The problem is that you are iterating through a collection with `enumerateChildNodesWithName`. You then try to remove elements from that collection while you are still iterating through it (in other words mutating the array while still enumerating it), and that is what causes this error.

One solution could be to store elements that should be removed in a new array like so:

```
dispatch_async(updateQueue, { () -> Void in
        var nodesToBeRemoved = [SKNode]()
        self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("lockGreen", usingBlock: { (lockGreen, stop) -> Void in
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, lockGreen.frame) && keyGreenCollected {
                nodesToBeRemoved.append(lockGreen)
            }
        })
    })
```

and then, once you're done iterating, maybe you can call `removeChildrenInArray(_ nodes: [AnyObject]!)` on `SKNode` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/removeChildrenInArray:)

You can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626462/error-when-attempting-to-remove-node-from-parent-using-fast-enumeration) for more details.